# How do I download all videos directly from a given channel from YouTube?

Tags: download, youtube

Is there any way to download all videos available from a given channel?

Suppose [there](http://www.youtube.com/user/Joes2Pros#g/u) are 16 videos, how can I download all videos at once?

Currently I have to download one after another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [BYTubeD - Bulk YouTube video Downloader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bytubed-bulk-youtube-video-dow/)   is what you're looking for.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/download-videos-youtube-playlist/)

Comment: An answer with just a link is not good form. Please provide a bit more info the next time. Adding this took only a minute.